# Huge gap issue in IE9 only at the footer of the page

Tags: internet-explorer-9, footer

I'm having issues with a huge footer space on my blog that only shows up in IE9. http://datilledm.com I have looked at the other posts about this are and the fixes they suggested have not worked.

Here is my Footer.php

```
    <?php global $data; ?>
    <?php if(isset($data['show_footer'])&&$data['show_footer'] ){ ?>
        <!-- START FOOTER-->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="footer-sidebar-container">
                <div class="container"><div class="row">
                <?php
                        global $footerGrid, $data;
                        $grid = (isset($data['footer_layout'])&&$data['footer_layout'] != '') ? $data['footer_layout']:'4';
                        $grid = $footerGrid[$grid];
                        $i = 1;
                        foreach (split('-', $grid) as $g) {
                            echo "<div class='span$g'>";
                            dynamic_sidebar("footer-sidebar-$i");
                            $i++;
                            echo "</div>";
                        } ?>
                </div></div>
                </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- END FOOTER -->
    <?php } ?>
        <div class="sub-footer">
            <div class="container"><div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="copyright"><?php echo $data['copyrighttext']; ?></div>
                        <div class="footer-bottom-menu"><?php footer_navigation(); ?></div>
                    </div>
            </div></div>
        </div> 
</div>
<!-- End Wrapper -->
<?php
//Google Analytics Code
    if ($data['google_analytics']){
    echo stripslashes($data['google_analytics']);
    } ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't see any problem in the code and the footer looks exactly the same in Chrome, Opera and even in IE8 & IE9.

Comment: Exactly Drejon. Which is why I don't understand why IE9 is treating page differently and creating a huge post footer gap.

Comment: It's below the footer if you scroll down. See the [link](http://datilledm.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/footer-gap.png)